# CoreML MLModel prediction progress

Tags: ios, coreml, mlmodel

We are trying to understand how to visualize `CoreML` `MLModel` `.predict` "waiting time" for our users, UI-wise.

Is there any way to estimate the time or get the actual progress of the `MLModel` prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no API for this.

If your model takes so long that users have to wait for it, it can be argued the model is too large.

Assuming that the model doesn't take 10s of seconds, putting up an indeterminate waiting animation is the best you can do.

Comment: Hey Matthijs! I just published an interesting question and also linked your library, I'm wondering if it's possible for you to take a look, it's regarding efficiency mostly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67787342/use-first-mlmodel-mlmultiarray-output-and-second-mlmodel-mlmultiarray-input